# Move constructor, non-const copy constructor, list's emplace in VS2010

Tags: c++

I'm new to move constructor and quite confused with VS2010 behavior.
I design a move constructor (of class A) which in my knowledge is like this:

```
A(A&& input) {some code}
```

When I use list's emplace and put an instance of class A:

```
mylist.emplace(a);
```

My move constructor is not called, and a non-const copy constructor is called instead:

```
A(A& input) {the same code as move constructor}
```

On the other hand when I do this:

```
mylist.emplace(A(2));
```

My move constructor is called like it supposed to. So, my question is:

1. Why is list's emplace call my non-const copy constructor instead of my move constructor?
2. Is the non-const copy constructor is actually an alternative way to define a move constructor?
3. Is this behavior is correct (for a c++0x compiler) or it just VS2010's behavior?

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: If your copy constructor has the same behavior as your move constructor, isn't the class seriously broken?

Comment: @UncleBens: Not necessarily, both may do a copy.

Comment: @ybungalobill: In such a case, why define (rather than perhaps disable) the move constructor? And if the copy constructor makes a copy, why should it take a non-const reference?

Comment: @UncleBens: because the guy studies C++0x here. Otherwise why does the copy constructor take a non-const reference?

Comment: Actually I add the non-const copy constructor for testing only, after my program crash. It's not part of the design XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mylist.emplace(a);
```

Here `a` is an l-value, hence it's copied rather than moved. You need to `move` it explicitely:

```
mylist.emplace(std::move(a));
```

Yes, the behavior is correct.